# Show all conversation with a contact

Tags: android, sms, android-intent

How to show standard activity with conversation for a contact?
For example when I enter to messages I see conversation, one for each contact, when I tap on a conversation I see all messages from this conversation. How can I show for a phone number such conversation from my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to access the messages database using content providers and there u can write an appropriate query to get all the messages related to a particular contact and then render the messages in your activity as you please.